# Linux creating an alias schema (a family of aliases) or something with similar effect

Tags: bash

A collection of aliases that I personally have got used to are the following:

```
alias ..="cd ../"
alias ...="cd ../../"
alias ....="cd ../../../"
```

I add them to my bash configuration, sometimes adding a few more following the same pattern.

**Question:** How can I obtain the same functionality for an arbitrary number of dots? Namely make it that an input `.^n` (n dots) results in applying the `cd ../` command n times.

Perhaps `alias` alone cannot express that, but it seems like Bash (it has loops and conditionals) might be able to do it. Unfortunately my knowledge of it is quite elementary. Maybe the name of the command changes makes it not possible. I just don't know.

Comment: Maybe instead of defining an arbitrary number of `.^n` aliases you should consider creating a function that accepts an argument which determines how many parent directories to traverse

Comment: @h0r53 Yes, that could be possible workaround. Let justify a little seeking for a solution that uses exactly just repeated dots. My question came from a habit. Understand how pressing mindlessly the '.' a number of times feels more comfortable (at least to me) than composing a function call syntax. You are completely right that what you said can solve it, but let me still seek if it exists a solution for this exact input.

Comment: @plot I understand. My presumption is it either isn't possible or it is very impractical.

Comment: A function would be my first choice too. Something like `function up { local res; for i in $(seq 1 $1); do res="../$res"; done; cd $res; }` should work. Of couse, you chould make a loop that creates aliases for some arbitrary large number of dots too.

Comment: For more sophisticated solutions around `cd` enhancements, have a look at [`z`](https://github.com/rupa/z) and [`j`](https://github.com/wting/autojump).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```sh
strrepeat() {
    local str=$1 count=$2
    local i result
    for ((i=1; i<=count; i++)); do
        result+=$str
    done
    printf "%s" "$result"
}

ascend() {
    local count=${1:-1}
    cd "$(strrepeat "../" "$count")"
}

for i in {1..8}; do
    alias ".$(strrepeat "." $i)"="ascend $i"
done
```

That generates 8 aliases that ascend the obvious number of directories.

---

If we change the alias for `..` to

```sh
alias ..=ascend
```

then you can write `.. 6`
instead of `.......`
and plain `..` still goes up 1 level.

Comment: I see. Let me see if I understood. This actually calls for the creation of the full sequence of aliases. The total number is hard-coded, but sure, for a reasonable number it would cover all cases that I would normally would use. Sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another, simpler way of doing it:

```
name=".."
cmd="cd .."
for _ in {1..10}
do
  alias "$name=$cmd"
  name+="." cmd+="/.."
done
```